# Static files: No such file or directory error in Django 1.4

Tags: python, django, static, webserver, django-1.4

I created an app locally with the django development server and now want to host it on the web.

I uploaded and installed everything on a server with python 2.7, django 1.4.5 and flup. Everything works fine until I try to use any static files. When my site tries to open a textfile it says: "No such file or directory" although the file definitely is in that folder.

Even weirder is that the server admin told me that his logs show the site isn't even looking in the directory it tells me, so the error message is "lying" about the path it is searching in.

Is there anything I have to do differently now that I want to host my program? On the development server it worked perfectly fine and now even after I tried every path combination in `settings.py` I could think of it won't work.

How do I get Django to serve static files on a production server?

**EDIT:**

When I try to visit http://ulli.cepheus.uberspace.de/fcgi-bin/mysite/polls/4/

I get the following error message but if you look at that link the textfile is clearly there.

> IOError at /polls/4/
>
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'http://ulli.cepheus.uberspace.de/static/m.txt'

Stack Overflow doesnt let me post my settings.py or anything because there are too many links in it... how can I show it to you?

Comment: Please provide the relevant fragments of `settings.py`

Comment: What are your `STATIC_URL`, `STATIC_ROOT`, `MEDIA_URL`, `MEDIA_ROOT` settings. Have you told your URLConf to serve static files? Have you collected static files?

Comment: As @Secator alludes to, we don't have enough information to really solve your problem, so can you show us the settings.py file?

Comment: The error message isn't 'lying' about where _Django_ is looking for the file. It just so happens that the path doesn't coincide with where _you_ think the files should be. ;)

EDIT: Incidentally, you should be serving your static files using a normal HTTP server, not Django. Use a server like Lighttpd or nginx to take care of that and also reverse proxy to Django.

Comment: We don't need all of your settings.py file, just the parts that Timmy O'Mahony displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to run

> `python manage.py collectstatic -l`

More information on the staticfiles app [can be found here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/).

Without more information, the best we can do is give you a link to read the documentation and you tell us what you've tried and what you haven't tried. If everything else is set up correctly, the running the command I gave you above should resolve one of the specific causes of your problem.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have helped! :)